# Hubspot PHP API cURL error 60: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: php, laravel-5, centos7, hubspot

I am using this [hubspot-php](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/hubspot-php) package in my php laravel v5 project.

It connects to hubspot and fetches deals. I have tested it locally and it works fine on my local machine. But when I pushed it to my production / live server (i.e., ec2-instance [centos 7] running via apache). It throws this error:

> cURL error 60: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized. (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

with status code: 500 ..

can anyone please help me fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: where you set up for certificate ?

Comment: I have checked in php.ini file, it is located in "/etc/httpd/ssl/" directory

Comment: do you setup curl for access api ?

Comment: at where? on the server yes we have curl setup already.. also, I am using `hubspot-php` wrapper for making calls to hubspot from my app..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your installation of PHP has one of these files, and that it’s up to date (otherwise download one here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).

Then set in php.ini:

```
curl.cainfo = <absolute_path_to> cacert.pem
```

If you are setting it at runtime, use:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
```

Comment: I already have this `cacert.pem` file and its up to date, also set in `php.ini` file too.